# Bluetooth headphones keep disconnecting when moveing laptop

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, laptop, headphones

I've recently installed the 22.04 LTS version on my Asus TUF laptop ( 11th Intel i7-11800 which recently had Win), but I am experiencing this weird problem with my Bluetooth headphones. They connect correctly at first , but they randomly disconnect after sometime. The weirder part is if I slightly move or drop the laptop, they disconnect. I am still new using Ubuntu and don't know yet and method to check logs of the problem